# Kotlin unresolved reference : inflate

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i was learning how to make recycler view in kotlin, and given code like this for my adapter

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_HEADER -> MenuHeaderHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_header))
            ITEM_MENU -> MenuItemHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_menu))
            else -> throw throw IllegalArgumentException("Undefined view type")
        }
    }
```

and my Class MenuHeaderHolder

```
class MenuHeaderHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val itemHeader = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderItem) as TextView

    fun bindContent(text: String){
        itemHeader.text = text
    }
}
```

but i get error unresolved reference : inflate, how fox this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead,

```
       val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_HEADER -> MenuHeaderHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header,parent,false))
            ITEM_MENU -> MenuItemHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu,parent,false))
            else -> throw throw IllegalArgumentException("Undefined view type")
        }
```

Comment: i got unresolved reference : inflate in ````val inflater = Inflate.from(parent.context)````

Comment: my bad, check the answer now